# TypeScript Typed Function void Should Not Compile

Tags: typescript

In the four functions below, the first two correctly return a number and the TypeScript compiler compiles them.

The third correctly causes a TypeScript compilation error but the fourth does not even though I expected it would?

```
// OK
let addNumbers: (a: number, b: number, c: number) => number = function (a, b, c) {
    return a + b + c;
};

// OK
let addNumbersTwo = function (a: number, b: number, c: number): number {
    return a + b + c;
};

// Correct compilation error
let addNumbersThree = function (a: number, b: number, c: number): void {
    return a + b + c;
};

// Should not compile? Should give same error as addNumbersThree above
let addNumbersFour: (a: number, b: number, c: number) => void = function (a, b, c) {
    return a + b + c;
};
```

[TypeScript Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0Alet%20addNumbers%3A%20(a%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20number%2C%20c%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20number%20%3D%20function%20(a%2C%20b%2C%20c)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20a%20%2B%20b%20%2B%20c%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0Alet%20addNumbersTwo%20%3D%20function%20(a%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20number%2C%20c%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20a%20%2B%20b%20%2B%20c%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Correct%20compliation%20error%0D%0Alet%20addNumbersFour%20%3D%20function%20(a%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20number%2C%20c%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20a%20%2B%20b%20%2B%20c%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Should%20not%20compile%3F%20Should%20give%20same%20error%20as%20addNumbersFour%0D%0Alet%20addNumbersThree%3A%20(a%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20number%2C%20c%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3D%20function%20(a%2C%20b%2C%20c)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20a%20%2B%20b%20%2B%20c%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B)

Comment: Related: [Why are functions returning non-void assignable to function returning void?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `(whatever) => whatever` is assignable to `(whatever) => void`.

Since a void returning function is expected to discard whatever nonexistent return value it has.

```
someVoidReturningFunction(args); // result doesn't get assigned or used.
```

It doesn't matter if in reality `someVoidReturningFunction` actually does return a value, and it just gets discarded.

In short: **Giving your functions an explicit return value of void is a sign that consuming code should not care about the returned result**.

Here's an example from [the docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void):

```
function callMeMaybe(callback: () => void) {
    callback();
}
let items = [1, 2];
callMeMaybe(() => items.push(3));
```

Technically speaking, `items.push(3)` will return a number (the new `length` of `items`). However, specifying a `void` callback actually allows us to pass a callback with any return value, and indicate that the return value will be discarded.

---

The same reasoning applies to missing arguments.

```
let foo: ((a: number, b: number) => number) = () => 42; // compiles
```

Because you can still call `foo(1, 2)` and get a number, even if those variables are unused in practice.